# What does the function parameter without a dollar sign mean?

Tags: php, function, oop, parameters, type-hinting

I've been studying PHP OOP and I came across this interesting function declaration:

```
class ShopProductWriter {

    public $products = array();

    public function addProduct(ShopProduct $shopProduct) {
        //code here..
    }
}
```

notice how the first parameter of the `addProduct` function `ShopProduct` doesn't have a dollar sign? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

it is not a parameter. it is the type definition of $shopProduct. this function takes only 1 parameter so $shopProduct can only be a ShopProduct class

Answer (score 1):

It's typehinting.

A parameter-list has to be comma-separated. This stands in front of a parameter and declares the parameter's type.

Your example typehint is for an object of the class `ShopProduct`.

Meaning: If something else was passed, like an integer or an array, the method would throw an exception. (It reflects inheritance. Assume there was an instance of `SpecificShopProduct`, a class that would be extending `ShopProduct`, you could pass that as well.)

It is possible to typehint objects and an array, an Class or an Interface. It is not possible to typehint normal variables types like integers or a string, and you cannot typehint an array of objects.

```
public function foo(array someArray, LoggerInterface $logger)
{
}
```

Yet for some of the other types you could use phpDoc comments, yet those are for readability and IDE support, they would not enforce a type; meaning you would have to take to check for yourself that a correct type was passed.

```
/**
 * @param ShopProductWriter[] arrayOfObjects
 * @param int $someInt
 * @param string $someString
 */

public function foo(array arrayOfObjects, $someInt, $someString)
{
}
```

Comment: I love it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I cant at the moment. but as soon as I get 15 reputation pts. I'll come back here to finish the deed